# When i click next to button to scroll another image nothing will showing Just Blank page

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm using swiper js for website to show images slider but the problem is when scroll to next page nothing showing just a blank page. Please help on this. Im using react as front-end

Thankyou!

Swiper js Next page is not working in react js `

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.